# Route requests based on the Accept header in Python web frameworks

Tags: python, pyramid

I have some experience with different web frameworks (Django, web.py, Pyramid and CherryPy), and I'm wondering in which one will it be easier and hopefully cleaner to implement a route dispatcher to a different "view/handler" based on the "Accept" header and the HTTP method e.g.:

```
Accept: application/json
POST /post/
```

is handled different than:

```
Accept: text/html
POST /post/
```

So the request gets routed to the particular view of the corresponding handler of the MIME "application/json" and the HTTP method "POST".

I do know how to implement something like that in CherryPy, but I lose the use of the CherryPy tools for the internal redirection of the request because I'm calling the specific method directly instead of automagically from the dispatcher. Another option is to implement a full new dispatcher from scratch, but that's the last option.

I'm aware of the alternative to use extensions in the url  like `/post.json` or `/post/.json`, but I'm looking to keep the same url?

Comment: This question is damn hard to answer for all frameworks at once, making it too broad for SO, in my opinion. For pyramid, use a [view predicate](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/viewconfig.html#predicate-arguments), registering two views each with a different `accept` predicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes I think you are right, it is too broad :(, but your alternative seems like a good way to do it, I wasn't expecting an answer with all the frameworks just a way to do it in one of them.

Comment: Okay, worked it out to a full answer then, if that is enough for you. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If all you are looking for is *one* framework that can do this easily, then use [`pyramid`](http://www.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/about).

Pyramid view definitions are made with [predicates](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/viewconfig.html#view-configuration-parameters), not just routes, and a view only matches if all predicates match. One such predicate is the `accept` predicate, which does exactly what you want; make view switching depending on the `Accept` header easy and simple:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

@view_config(route_name='some_api_name', request_method='POST', accept='application/json')
def handle_someapi_json(request):
    # return JSON

@view_config(route_name='some_api_name', request_method='POST', accept='text/html')
def handle_someapi_html(request):
    # return HTML
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do this in Django, and so I wrote a piece of middleware to make it possible: http://baltaks.com/2013/01/route-requests-based-on-the-http-accept-header-in-django

Here is the code:

```
# A simple middleware component that lets you use a single Django
# instance to serve multiple versions of your app, chosen by the client
# using the HTTP Accept header.
# In your settings.py, map a value you're looking for in the Accept header
# to a urls.py file.
# HTTP_HEADER_ROUTING_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP = {
#     u'application/vnd.api-name.v1': 'app.urls_v1'
# }

from django.conf import settings

class HTTPHeaderRoutingMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            for content_type in settings.HTTP_HEADER_ROUTING_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP:
                if (request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT'].find(content_type) != -1):
                    request.urlconf = settings.HTTP_HEADER_ROUTING_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP[content_type]
        except KeyError:
            pass # use default urlconf (settings.ROOT_URLCONF)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        return response
```

Comment: I think it would have been better to just post that code here, given that it's so short.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suite sure what you mean by "internal redirection", but if you look at [the code](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/a2c05b87434edd49fe0b6d8ed06943245c99a3a6/cherrypy/_cptools.py?at=default#cl-502) you can see that tools.accept is a really thin wrapper around [lib.cptools.accept](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/lib/cptools.html#cherrypy.lib.cptools.accept), which you can call from your own code easily. Hand it a list of Content-Types your server can send, and it will tell you which one the client prefers, or raise 406 if the types you emit and the types the client accepts don't overlap.

Comment: In particular in cherrypy, I'm thinking something like [this](https://gist.github.com/4356820), what do you think?

Comment: I just wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/4358637) in the middle of the morning/night that does what I want in cherrypy, yes it is a little convoluted, probably I'll improve that after getting some sleep or after christmas :).