# Route requests based on the Accept header in Flask

Tags: python, flask, http-headers, werkzeug

I would like to route to a different Flask views based on the Accept HTTP header, for example:

```
@api.route('/test', accept='text/html')
def test_html():
    return "<html><body>Test</body></html>"

@api.route('/test', accept='text/json')
def test_json():
    return jsonify(test="Test")
```

I haven't found relevant option in [Werkzeug Rule constructor](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Rule), which is used by Flask. Is it a missing feature or is it possible to achieve the same effect differently, for example by intercepting and modifying URL path before routing?

I don't want to merge the views into one because it would complicate code significantly, there are many of them and they reside in different blueprints.

I am aware that [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998607) has been asked, but nobody answered it using Flask. It's possible to do it in different web frameworks, for example in Pyramid using [predicates](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/viewconfig.html#predicate-arguments) - sample code can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14003847/4619705).

Comment: [Flask-Restful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.2/) does something *similar*; it has pluggable support to format view results according to the `Accept` header. By default it supports JSON only, but is extensible. See [*Content Negotiation*](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.2/extending.html#content-negotiation).

Comment: It's approach is different however; it builds on [pluggable views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/views/) to do the final routing; Flask offers a method-based dispatch already, I'm sure the same technique could be used to do Accept-based dispatch in a similar way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, that's interesting. I believe Flask uses Werkzeug to do HTTP method-based routing. Pluggable views can help organizing the code a bit better, but it's not ideal as ultimately I register only one route.

Comment: Yes, Werkzeug takes care of the routing, and that mechanism has no support for header-based routing. It only supports methods, extending this is not going to be simple or easy.

Comment: If anyone's interested, I wrote a [decorator](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/audriusk/4ARz) which allows this kind of routing in Flask.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas: this is very nice idea to chose function based on request - I forgot how flexible Python is. I haven't tested it yet, since I moved to a different project right now, but it will work. I am not very familiar with Stack Overflow standards - do you want to convert your comment to an answer, or should I just close the question as resolved?

Comment: I posted the code as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a [decorator](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/audriusk/4ARz) which does that (copying here for posterity). It's just a rough idea that could be improved further (e.g. returning `406 Not Acceptable` response instead of using the default handler when there are no handlers that match given MIME type). More explanations are in the comments.

```py
import functools
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

def accept(func_or_mimetype=None):
    """Decorator which allows to use multiple MIME type handlers for a single
    endpoint.
    """

    # Default MIME type.
    mimetype = 'text/html'

    class Accept(object):
        def __init__(self, func):
            self.default_mimetype = mimetype
            self.accept_handlers = {mimetype: func}
            functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            default = self.default_mimetype
            mimetypes = request.accept_mimetypes
            best = mimetypes.best_match(self.accept_handlers.keys(), default)
            # In case of Accept: */*, choose default handler.
            if best != default and mimetypes[best] == mimetypes[default]:
                best = default
            return self.accept_handlers[best](*args, **kwargs)

        def accept(self, mimetype):
            """Register a MIME type handler."""

            def decorator(func):
                self.accept_handlers[mimetype] = func
                return func
            return decorator

    # If decorator is called without argument list, return Accept instance.
    if callable(func_or_mimetype):
        return Accept(func_or_mimetype)

    # Otherwise set new MIME type (if provided) and let Accept act as a
    # decorator.
    if func_or_mimetype is not None:
        mimetype = func_or_mimetype
    return Accept

@app.route('/')
@accept     # Or: @accept('text/html')
def index():
    return '<strong>foobar</strong>'

@index.accept('application/json')
def index_json():
    return jsonify(foobar=True)

@index.accept('text/plain')
def index_text():
    return 'foobar\n', 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
```

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question but I ended up here looking for something similar so I hope it helps someone else.

[flask_accept](https://pypi.org/project/flask_accept/) has the functionality to handle different Accept types through different routes.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_accept import accept
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@accept('text/html')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@hello_world.support('application/json')
def hello_world_json():
    return jsonify(result="Hello World!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

if you just want to reject requests depending on whether they are a specific data type you could also use [Flask-Negotiate](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Negotiate/)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_negotiate import consumes, produces

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/consumes_json_only')
@consumes('application/json')
def consumes_json_only():
    return 'consumes json only'
```

> When one tries to access the endpoint without a valid Accept header:

```
$ curl localhost:5000 -I
HTTP 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

Comment: Thanks for info, it looks like new libraries / possibilities became available.

Comment: see github.com/di/flask-accept/issues/11 - couldn't first get it to work had to upgrade to python3.8 on macports, make sure all port selects are o.k. reboot and upgrade liclipse python environment.

Answer (score 6):

You can return different response types based on the Accept header using [request](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Request.html).  Example.

```
if request.accept_mimetypes['application/json']:
           return jsonify(<object>), '200 OK'
```