# How to set accepted request header to Content-Type: text/plain in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

How can I setup what headers my flask app should accept?

I need to call is using only Content-Type: text/plain
It returns an 500 internal error if Content-Type: Application/json is not used

Here is my app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
cors = CORS(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Priser(db.Model):
    pris = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    kategori = db.Column(db.Text)


class getPriser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()
        newPris = Priser(kategori = data['kategori'],pris = data['pris'])
        db.session.add(newPris)
        db.session.flush()
        db.session.commit()
        return {'kategori':newPris.kategori, 'pris':newPris.pris}

api.add_resource(getPriser, '/getpriser')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791613/route-requests-based-on-the-accept-header-in-flask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Route requests based on the Accept header in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791613/route-requests-based-on-the-accept-header-in-flask)